# Как организовать перетаскивание блоков и запоминание в базе их положения?

Tags: jquery, html, php, css, javascript

Суть вопроса в следующем. Есть сайт (вернее админка сайта), на котором реализовано перемещение блоков мышкой: http://test.landix.ru/admin/sort (логин и пароль: admin). Как можно реализовать такой эффект перемещения блоков, и чтобы положение блоков записывалось в базу.

Comment: Это drag&drop : http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop

Comment: А как потом всё это дело в базу MySQL поместить?

Comment: Координаты ajax-ом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Добавить всем блокам в БД кокйое-то поле типа order_num, по которому и будем сортировать
2. При перетаскивании блока отсылать ajax-ом id текущего блока, его исходную позицию и конечную (позиции - это числа, предположительно order_num), дальше работа за бекендом:

   а) если исходная позиция больше конечной -  инкремент всех order_num, которые больше  конечной позиции + текущему блоку ставим order_num = конечная позиция;

   б) если исходная позиция меньше конечной - декремент всех order_num в диапазоне (исходная; конечная] + ставим текущему блоку order_num = конечная

Comment: Нашёл вот-такую штуку http://jqueryui.com/sortable/. Скажите пожалуйста, как можно занести положения в таблицу, исользуя её? Я с аяксом просто не очень дружу.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/